# Is it possible to typedef a multidimensional array of uncertain size? [C]

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, typedef

I am trying currently to solve a specific task. For this task I try to exercise all the skills I have learned so far. Since I am dealing with a multidimensional array a lot I wanted to typedef it as usual.

This time the array has to be editable by the program in size.

```
typedef char grid[][];
```

this is what I tried in my special header file. I am getting the error

```
error: array type has incomplete element type
```

I post the complete code if it is necessary to see more details:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "functions.h"
#include "tester.h"
#include "magic.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int size = getSize();
    grid pascal[size][size];
    drawGrid(pascal, size);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

functions.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "magic.h"
#include <math.h>

/*  C array: Pascal triangle exercise
*  By using two-dimensional array, write C program to display
*  a table that represents a Pascal triangle of any size.
*
*  In Pascal triangle, the first and the second rows are set to 1.
*  Each element of the triangle (from the third row downward) is the sum
*  of the element directly above it and the element to the left of the
*  element directly above it. See the example Pascal triangle(size=5) below:
*
*
*  1
*  1    1
*  1    2   1
*  1    3   3   1
*  1    4   6   4   1
*
*/

int getSize(void)
{
    int size;
    printf("Please enter the size of the Pascal Triangle:");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    printf("\n");

    size = (int) sqrt(size);
    printf("Pascal Triangle will be %d big", (size*size));
    return size;
}

void createVoid(grid pascal, int size)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while(i < size){
        while (j < size){
            if (j > i){
                pascal[i][j] = ' ';
            }
            j++;
       }
       i++;
    }
}

void createNumbers(grid pascal, int size)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while(i < size){
        while (j < size){
            if (j <= i){
                if (i == 0){
                    pascal[i][j] = '1';
                }else if (i == j){
                    pascal[i][j] = '1'
                }else{
                    pascal[i][j] = pascal[i][j-1] - VALUE_ZERO + pascal[i-1][j];
                }
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

void printGrid(grid pascal)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (i < size){
        while (j < size){
            printf ("%3c", pascal[i][j]);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

void drawGrid(grid pascal, int size)
{
    createVoid(pascal, size);
    createNumbers(pascal, size);
    printGrid(pascal);
}
```

functions.h

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H
#include "magic.h"

int getSize(void);
void drawGrid(grid pascal, int size);
void createVoid(grid pascal, int size);
void createNumbers(grid pascal, int size);
void printGrid(grid pascal, int size);

#endif // FUNCTIONS_H
```

magic.h

```
#ifndef MAGIC_H
#define MAGIC_H
#include <stdlib.h>

#define VALUE_ZERO '0'

typedef char grid[][];

#endif // MAGIC_H
```

Comment: Somehow I do not see question about `typedef` being duplication of the by question about initialization.

Comment: @sg7 using typedef makes the language somehow different from the way was written ?

Comment: @Michi - Well, judging by PC Luddite comments under my post it was ALL about `typedef` not about practical solution and initialization. First I understood the question in terms of solution and solving the problem. But after being down-voted on my post I realized that one can have different point of view. It can be about `typedef` or it can be about dynamic array. See: _"The asker was writing about typedefs though, not really about the creation of dynamically sized arrays... – PC Luddite"_

Comment: why not just use `typedef char **grid;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `typedef` declaration `char grid[][]` is illegal, because you cannot omit the righmost indice. In general (three and more dimensions), you can omit only the leftmost one.

The C99 standard introduced a way to declare and define functions with multidimensional arrays of unknown size (known as VLAs<sup>1</sup>). The proper form to declare such function would be:

```
void drawGrid(int, char pascal[*][*]);
```

or if you prefer to keep parameters' names:

```
void drawGrid(int size, char pascal[size][size]);
```

The latter (and only the latter) can be used for a defintion too.

Note that the `typedef` declaration cannot be applied to VLAs at file scope (that is, outside of any function). Refering to C11 (N1570 draft), §6.7.8/2 *Type definitions*:

> If a typedef name specifies a variably modified type then it shall
>   have block scope.

---

<sup>1)</sup> Of course, VLAs could be one-dimensional as well, like `int n = 100; int a[n] = {0};`.

Comment: I strongly doubt you can specify the inner dimension as `*`. How would the compiler know the length?

Comment: @Olaf: It would assume, that size is taken from the precedecing parameter(s). In this case (an single `int`), both sizes has to be evaluated using that parameter (can be arbitratry expresions like `2*size`, but the parameter must be present within them). AFAIR there is an GNU extension, that allows to put size _after_ the array parameter(s).

Comment: I know that about the VLA with an expression in the brackets but for the `*`-only version, I did not find anything supporting it is allowed in an inner dimension. See 6.7.6.2p4: "If the size is * instead of being an expression, the array type is a variable length array type of unspecified size, which can only be used in declarations or type names with function prototype scope". The inner dimensions are **not** at function prototype scope, but at the scope of the outer dimension. Difference to `[]` is it is a complete type and you can `typedef int arr[*][123];`, but use only for parameter.

Comment: @Olaf: This could be a valid point for a DR. But I believe, that intent was that `[*][*]` is perfectly valid. See 6.7.6.3/p21 (Example 5).

Comment: Hmm, you are right. I really wonder how that is supposed to work. At least it is a bad idea from a documentation view. Actually I never use that star-syntax. OTOH it is the only way to `typedef` such an array type for arguments. Re. defect: I'd say it takes the lengths from the other arguments, left to right. Which implies there is a problem is you don't pass them and what if you mix with other types. Strange syntax, though, I just use the "normal" VLA syntax. (Wonder how/if Doxygen can handle this)